# Redeclaration error in Angular 8 when adding external JS script

Tags: javascript, angular

I am adding manually an external JS script into my component. The script works fine, but I can't inject it again.

```
var div = this.document.getElementById("div-element");
div.appendChild(script);
```

I am trying to delete that script firstly and add it to DOM again but I am getting en error:
"redeclaration of const".
I checked many times and I am sure the old script was removed from DOM completly.

Seems Angular keeps javascript somewhere in memory, do you know guys how to handle it?

Comment: Once a script is added to the dom, it's executed. Deleting the script tag and re-adding it, causes the script to be executed again, which causes the error. You'll need to change your script to be able to re-added without colliding with itself.

But curious, why are you re-adding the script?

Comment: "*Seems Angular keeps javascript somewhere in memory*" the browser does. Angular works in the browser.

Comment: @Alan The script is provided by 3rd party service. Do you have any idea how I could adjust my code to avoid this error? There are some const variables declared and Angular complains about them.

Comment: @tylkonachwile You could host a copy of the script yourself, assuming it was open source. However, I am curious what is your reason for deleting and re-adding the script tag?

Answer (score 0):

If you know variables in this script, you can write a function, called, when component need to be destroyed:

```
function deleteExternalCode() {
    delete nameVar1;
    delete nameVar2;
    ....
}
```